# What does the yellow square mean?

Tags: temperature

I was running this code:

```python
for value in range(1,1000001):
    print(value)
```

And as it was running i noticed a yellow square in the upper right corner.
I know that the red & rainbow squares mean CPU is to hot and not enough power respectively but i don't remember what the yellow square means and I couldn't find where i saw it. So I'd like to know, what does the yellow square mean?

Comment: Off topic, but why would you use such worthless code?

Comment: @Jacobm001 I wanted to see how long it would take, instead it crashed. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The yellow square denotes a high CPU temperature warning, and that CPU overclocking has been disabled. If I remember correctly the square appears when the temperature reaches 75 degrees Celsius, and turns red at 80. The Pi will throttle back the CPU frequency to prevent overheating the Pi. You may want to look into some additional cooling (fan/heatsink) or a different case to avoid thermal issues. I saw this behavior with a new Pi3 in the foundation's case - the solution was as simple as removing the cover when watching YouTube videos at 2x speed.

More info can be found [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=82373)